# How to revert back data entry if second query fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Heres my code:

```
data = {
    "order_type":"order",
    "user_id":user_id,
    "order_total":order_total,
    ...
}
serialzier = UserOrderSer(data=data)
if serialzier.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serialzier.save()

product_data = []
for i in all_response:
    product_data.append({
        "order_id": serialzier.data['order_id'],
        "product_id":i['product_id'],
        "product_name":i['product_name'],
        "product_price": i['selling_price'],
        ...
    })

product_serializer = UserOrderProductSer(data=product_data,many=True)
if product_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    product_serializer.save()
```

If the `product_serializer.is_valid` fails, then i want the `serialzier = UserOrderSer(data=data)` entry to revert back. Since, i'm using id of 1st entry in 2nd entry i cannot check `.is_valid` both at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic
> allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the
> database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully
> completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an
> exception, the changes are rolled back.

You can use `transaction.atomic()`